# C# generate bit string randomly "0001", "1010", etc

Tags: c#, linq

I need to generate a 4 bit string randomly and set to a property via Linq.

Right now is hardcoded:

```
        // TODO: hardcode bit string
        employees = employees.Select(x => { x.Options = "0101"; return x; }).ToList();
```

I need Options to be random so I can get all 4 bit possible values: "0001","0010", "0011" and so on.

I was thinking on having a Random `0` to `1` variable and generate the value 4 times and concatenate the string.

> Any clue on how to implement this?

Comment: You already said how you could do it, which part of it are you having problems with?

Comment: Why don't you try your idea first before asking here?

Comment: Just generate a random integer once and use its first four bits.

Comment: Your idea is a good one.  Just move forward with that.

Comment: I guess I can't use the actual linq code right? I guess I will have to loop every object inside employees manually.

Comment: Side note - since all you do is to set an existing object property, there is no real LINQ in your code (in fact it is LINQ anti usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rand = new Random();
Convert.ToString(rand.Next(16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0')
```

Explanation:

The first line creates a random object, nothing too hard to understand here... The second line first generates a random number between 0 - 15 (`rand.Next(16)`). Then it puts the random number into `Convert.ToString`. The method converts to number to base 2 (because the second parameter is 2). However, this still is not enough because if the random number can be represented by 3 bits or fewer, the returned string will not have the leading 0s. That's why I used `PadLeft` to add them in.

Answer (score 1):

If speed is critical, such as this operating being called in a loop, it would be more efficient to use a 16 element string array of all possible values and select the element randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Convert.ToString(int, 2);
```

This will convert the int to base 2 `string`.

Where `int` is a random number up to 16 not included.